# error rendering facebook react with java (clojure) in the server: Cannot read property "__reactAutoBindMap"

Tags: clojure, reactjs, nashorn, isomorphic-javascript

I'm trying render my react component in the server but I'm having some problems, I followed this article

http://augustl.com/blog/2014/jdk8_react_rendering_on_server/

this is my code

```
(def nashorn (.getEngineByName (ScriptEngineManager.) "nashorn"))

(defn <render-react-comp [template-name data]
  (let [remove-react-prefix (fn [react-word] (clojure.string/replace react-word #"react-" ""))]
    (go
      (dlet [component-name (remove-react-prefix template-name)
             template (<! (<react-template! component-name))
             lib (<! (<get-react-lib))
             evaluation-string
                  (str "React.renderToString(" component-name "(" (write-str data) "))")]

            (. nashorn eval "var global = this;")
            (. nashorn eval "var console = {}")
            (. nashorn eval "console.debug = print;")
            (. nashorn eval "console.warn = print;")
            (. nashorn eval "console.log = print;")
            (. nashorn eval (.toString lib))
            (. nashorn eval template)
            (. nashorn eval evaluation-string))))) ;;<---fails here!!!
```

the dlet macro print this

all these bindings are Strings...

```
component-name : MyComponent
template : var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return React.DOM.h1(null, 'Hi, ' + this.props.msg)
    }
})

evaluation-string : React.renderToString(MyComponent({"msg":"HI!!!!!"}))
lib : "....react lib here ...a lot of lines"
```

this is the error message..fails in the evaluation-string line

```
Exception in thread "async-dispatch-27" java.lang.Error: javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "__reactAutoBindMap" from undefined in <eval> at line number 5816
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1148)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "__reactAutoBindMap" from undefined in <eval> at line number 5816
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:586)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:570)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:525)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:521)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:192)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
    at debgtest.viewEngine$_LT_render_react_comp$fn__11415$state_machine__6788__auto____11416$fn__11418.invoke(viewEngine.clj:126)
    at debgtest.viewEngine$_LT_render_react_comp$fn__11415$state_machine__6788__auto____11416.invoke(viewEngine.clj:111)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:940)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:944)
    at debgtest.viewEngine$_LT_render_react_comp$fn__11415.invoke(viewEngine.clj:111)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: <eval>:5816 TypeError: Cannot read property "__reactAutoBindMap" from undefined
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:58)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:214)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:186)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:173)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Undefined.lookupTypeError(Undefined.java:128)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Undefined.lookup(Undefined.java:113)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornLinker.java:98)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.java:176)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.java:124)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.LinkerServicesImpl.getGuardedInvocation(LinkerServicesImpl.java:144)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.DynamicLinker.relink(DynamicLinker.java:232)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval\_$7.L:4-1$L:4974$L:5802$L:5803(<eval>:5816)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval\_.runScript(<eval>:1)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:535)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:209)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:378)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:568)
    ... 18 more
```

I'm using the latest react version,  please let me know if you has idea what could be the issue, thanks so much guys!...

Answer (score 2):

since the last release it's necessary the function createFactory for create valid React components

this line

```
 (str "React.renderToString(" component-name "(" (write-str data) "))")
```

needs to be changed to

```
(str "React.renderToString(React.createFactory(" component-name ")(" (write-str data) "))")
```

React.createFactory returns a new function which you can pass your data in the first argument

React.createFactory(Component)({message : "React!!"})

Hope this help if someone has the same problem...